# Toggle element type on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code that is soposed to change the element type on click and back if the the user click anywere outsite the element.

The problem is that fore some reason in CodePen doesn't change at all on click, but in the original website does that only once then nothing.

The HTML

```
<div>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="btn"aria-hidden="true">Go</span></button>
</span>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


  $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
    var attrs = {};

    $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
      attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
    });

    this.replaceWith(function() {
      return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
    });
  }

  $('.input-group-btn button').changeElementType('div');





    $(function() {
  $(".input-group div").on("click", function(e) {
    $('.input-group-btn div').changeElementType('button');

    e.stopPropagation()
  });
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".input-group input") === false) {
        $('.input-group-btn button').changeElementType('div');
    }
  });
});


});
```

Here is the pen:
http://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/AXxKbG

Any ideas?

Comment: On console: `pen.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to instead add a comment, since what I'm about to mention is related to possible corrections on your implementation, and not a proper solution, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet to do that.

I noticed a few problems with your code, but I'm not sure if they're intended or not.

Starting with the HTML, you have this element `<span class="btn"aria-hidden="true">Go</span>` which has `class="btn"`. I'm not sure if you really want it there, since it's already used on its parent.

On the Javascript part, here `$(e.target).is(".input-group input")` you're expecting to match an element that has a parent with a class `.input-group` and the element itself is an `input`. One of the problems here is that you're not using `input` elements anywhere on your HTML (nor switching from any element on Javascript code for that matter). I believe you want it to be `button`. The other one (I'm not entirely sure about this), I don't think you'll ever be able to match the selector on the `.is()` function, since you're using a nested selector. The target will be the element where the event was triggered and it has its own type and/or id or class. That's what you'll have to use to check if that's the element you wanted (since you're using the function `.is()`).